# SQL / Add 2 zeros to String

Tags: sql

I want to add 2 zero to the right of the next function: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW()),`

So instead of: `1369047810`, I would get: `136904781000`

I try this:

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW()) + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2))))
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you need  to have time time multiplied by 100? Didn't you mean 1000?

Comment: In what way is the expression `'2013-05-20 07:03:30-04' * 100` meaningful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW()) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as a string, then you want to convert it to a string and then add the zeros.  Something like:

```
SELECT (cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW()) as varchar(255) + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2))))
```

I think the string conversion is safer than doing arithmetic, if you want a string in the end.  Multiplying values might cause arithmetic overflow.

Also, I associate the syntax `UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW())` with MySQL (as I write this, there is no database tag on the question).  The right syntax in that database would be:

```
select concat(cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW()) as varchar(255), '00')
```

Comment: Use '00' if its only two zeroes, replicate is a bit heavy in that case i guess. Other than that, if its way more than two zeroes, replicate comes in handy.

Comment: @CSharpie . . . I agree.  The bigger problem, though, is that the original formulation seemed to mix SQL Server and MySQL syntax.